# SFML Ressource Manager class , null pointer on textures

Tags: c++, textures, sfml

I wrote a chess game and am now trying to change the design to include a Ressource Manager class (I have heard this is more efficient?). I am having issues though with null pointers regarding textures. I am getting the same errors both in this minimal example and on my main application.

#### Expected behavior

I am expecting 4 circles to appear on the screen distanced by 100 pixels.

#### Actual behavior

The screen flashes, then closes immediately with a segmentation fault

## Minimally Reproducible Example

### RessourceManager.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

typedef unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<sf::Texture>> textureMap;

class RessourceManager {  
    string m_textureNames[1] = {"circle.png"};
    textureMap m_textures;

    public:
    RessourceManager(); // Constructor

    void loadRessources();
    void addTexture(const string& name);
    shared_ptr<sf::Texture> getTexture(const string &name);
};
```

### RessourceManager.cpp

```cpp
#include "RessourceManager.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

RessourceManager::RessourceManager() {};

void RessourceManager::addTexture(const string& name) { 
    shared_ptr<sf::Texture> texture = make_shared<sf::Texture>();
    texture->loadFromFile(name);
    m_textures.emplace(name, move(texture));
};

shared_ptr<sf::Texture> RessourceManager::getTexture(const string &name) {
    for(auto it = m_textures.begin();it != m_textures.end(); ++it) {
        if(it->first == name) {
            cout << "found" <<endl;
            return move(it->second);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
};

void RessourceManager::loadRessources() {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 1; ++i)  addTexture(m_textureNames[i]);
}
```

### main.cpp

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "RessourceManager.hpp"

void drawSquares(sf::RenderWindow&, RessourceManager&);

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 480), "SFML window");
    RessourceManager ressources; 
    ressources.loadRessources();

    while (window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }
        drawSquares(window, ressources);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}

void drawSquares(sf::RenderWindow& window ,RessourceManager& ressources) {
    for(int i = 20; i <= 320; ++i) {
        shared_ptr<sf::Texture> temp = ressources.getTexture("circle.png");
        sf::Sprite s(*temp);
        s.setPosition(i, i);

        window.draw(s);
    }
}
```

#### Output console

```
found
found
[1]    4445 segmentation fault  sudo ./main
```

---

#### Aditional information

Here I am using `shared_ptr` because I want multiple Sprites to point to the same texture (for instance 8 black pawns or 8 white pawns in a chess game). Further, I need these textures to move dynamically around on the screen so I must have them in the main loop in a standalone function.

### Things I have tried

1. In `drawSquares()` I tried to first define an array `shared_ptr<sf::Texture> textures[5];`, populate it with the textures returned from `ressources.getTexture()` and then use these textures on the sprites in the for loop, but with no success.
2. I have tried using `unique_ptr`
3. I have tried to write `sf::Sprite s(*(ressources.getTexture("circle.png")));` immediately, but also doesn't work.
4. I have read the SFML documentation on Textures and c++ variable scope/life time information, but I still can't understand what I am doing wrong in here.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer was found

Thanks to metaquarks on Discord, removing the `move()` wrappers in `move(it -> second)` and `.emplace(name. move(texture))` fixed the problem.

This is because after calling `get()`, the only thing keeping the texture alive is the pointer that was returned which is in this example dereferenced and passed as a non-owning reference, so it just dies. If one does not return using `move()`, both shared pointers keep it alive, and when the returned one eventually goes out of scope, it still exists because it is inside the map.